# Query not returning predicted results - what am I missing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the following queries:

```
SELECT [LISTING_ID] ,[COMPANY_NM]
FROM [InterAction_Test].[dbo].[INT_AUX_LISTING]
WHERE COMPANY_NM = 'IB Sample 12'
```

Returns:

```
LISTING_ID   COMPANY_NM
----------   ----------
335698       IB Sample 12
```

Then:

```
SELECT [LIST1_ID],[LIST2_ID],[CORRELATION_TYP_ID]
FROM [InterAction_Test].[dbo].[INT_AUX_LIST_LIST]
WHERE LIST1_ID = 335698
```

Returns:

```
LIST1_ID   LIST2_ID   CORRELATION_TYP_ID
--------   --------   ------------------
335698     139685     90
335698     139685     10003
335698     139685     10009
```

Then:

```
SELECT [LISTING_ID],[DISPLAY_NM]
FROM [InterAction_Test].[dbo].[INT_AUX_LISTING]
WHERE LISTING_ID = 139685
```

Returns:

```
LISTING_ID   DISPLAY_NM
----------   ----------
139685       Swisk, Bob
```

I then run:

```
SELECT dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_NM, INT_AUX_LISTING_1.DISPLAY_NM AS [Relationship Partner], 
INT_AUX_LISTING_2.DISPLAY_NM AS [Introducing Partner], INT_AUX_LISTING_3.DISPLAY_NM AS [Introduced By]
FROM dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING 
INNER JOIN dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST ON dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_LIST_ID = dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST.LIST1_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING AS INT_AUX_LISTING_1 ON dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST.LIST2_ID = INT_AUX_LISTING_1.LISTING_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST AS INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_1 ON dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_LIST_ID = INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_1.LIST1_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING AS INT_AUX_LISTING_2 ON INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_1.LIST2_ID = INT_AUX_LISTING_2.LISTING_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST AS INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_2 ON dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_LIST_ID = INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_2.LIST1_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING AS INT_AUX_LISTING_3 ON INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_2.LIST2_ID = INT_AUX_LISTING_3.LISTING_ID
GROUP BY dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_LIST_ID, dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_NM, INT_AUX_LISTING_1.DISPLAY_NM, INT_AUX_LISTING_2.DISPLAY_NM, INT_AUX_LISTING_3.DISPLAY_NM, dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST.CORRELATION_TYP_ID, INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_1.CORRELATION_TYP_ID, INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_2.CORRELATION_TYP_ID
HAVING (dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST.CORRELATION_TYP_ID = 90) AND (INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_1.CORRELATION_TYP_ID = 10003) AND (INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_2.CORRELATION_TYP_ID = 10009)
```

**This returns no rows**, when I'd expect it to return:

```
COMPANY_NM     Relationship Partner   Introducing Partner   Introduced By
----------     --------------------   -------------------   -------------
IB Sample 12   Swisk, Bob             Swisk, Bob            Swisk, Bob
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your having clause is nonsense. Having is for aggregates, eg having count(*) > 3 etc. your having should be a where.

Comment: This might be easier to debug if you provided the whole table structure and sample data.

Comment: Can you add `COMPANY_LIST_ID` to the select list for each of your queries against `INT_AUX_LISTING`, and update your question to include the results?

Comment: And don't forget to mark an answer if it is really help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your join conditions you are using `[INT_AUX_LISTING].[Company_List_ID]`but in the sample queries and data you provided the value is contained in the `[INT_AUX_LISTING].[Listing_ID]` column.

I created the sample data and changed the query to join on `[INT_AUX_LISTING].[Listing_ID]` and it works. See [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2edd/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think that in last line, where `HAVING` clause is, you need OR instead AND operator.

Like this:

...

```
GROUP BY dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_LIST_ID, dbo.INT_AUX_LISTING.COMPANY_NM, INT_AUX_LISTING_1.DISPLAY_NM, INT_AUX_LISTING_2.DISPLAY_NM, INT_AUX_LISTING_3.DISPLAY_NM, dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST.CORRELATION_TYP_ID, INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_1.CORRELATION_TYP_ID, INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_2.CORRELATION_TYP_ID
HAVING (dbo.INT_AUX_LIST_LIST.CORRELATION_TYP_ID = 90) OR (INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_1.CORRELATION_TYP_ID = 10003) OR (INT_AUX_LIST_LIST_2.CORRELATION_TYP_ID = 10009)
```

Comment: This is something else that could actually turn out to be a problem later on. Well spotted. Thanks a lot.